# QFileDialog: default file name based on current directory

Tags: pyqt, qt5, savefiledialog, qfiledialog

I was wondering is it possible to make the default file name dynamically change based on the current directory in the dialog? I think it is not possible with `QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()`, but could it be possible with customized `QFileDialog`? Here is a screenshot of the ideal dialog: [image: QFileDialog with filename]

I would appreciate all help!

Comment: like "name of the last child folder"+"extension" ???

Comment: It is not mandatory, but it would be nice to be able to set extension as well.